# Which design patterns are implemented by java.util.Currency?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Which design patterns are implemented by `java.util.Currency`, if any?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html

Comment: @Cylian et al: I think it's pretty clear what OP is asking. It is not a particularly interesting question for anybody who has at least skimmed through GoF:DP or Wikipedia, but I think it is clear. I took the liberty to reword it slightly anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is homework.

While there could be several design patterns at play in the implementation, when you see `getInstance`, you should **immediately** think Singleton:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

When the API manual at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html says:

> **The class is designed so that there's never more than one Currency 
>   instance for any given currency.** Therefore, there's no public
>   constructor.
>   You obtain a Currency instance using the getInstance methods.

(emphasis mine), well, you should think Singleton **again** - it's the Intent given by the [GoF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000SEIBB8) for the Singleton pattern, almost verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

`Currency` uses **Factory Method** design pattern to create instances of this class. Method `getInstance()` returns **Singleton** object per `Locale`, but `Currency` itself isn't pure Singleton - there might be multiple instances of this class (for different currencies).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if that's what you mean, but one way of looking at it would be to say it's singleton design pattern